# Calculating mean for the most occurring values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working with a big dataset. I want to calculate average price for each top selling (most occuring) brand.

```
top_brands = df['brand'].value_counts().head(10)
```

gives me the top 10 brands, but I also want the mean price in this result. So I tried...

```
top_brands = df[['brand', 'PRICE']].groupby('brand').mean().sort_values('brand')
```

but now I am getting average of each brand, not the top 10 brands.

How can I get average price for each of the top 10 brands only?

Comment: Since you can find out the top 10 brands, why not use that list to apply a filter on `df` before groupby? e.g. `df[df['brands'].isin(top_10_brands)][['brands','PRICE']].gropuby...`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I managed by using the following code

    top_brands = df['brand'].value_counts().head(10)

    top_avging = df[df['brand'].isin(top_brands.index)].groupby('brand')['PRICE'].mean()